# Apple Pages: Make a cell span two columns

Tags: pages

I have a table. I want a cell that spans two columns, so that text in this cell with span two columns. In Microsoft Word, I can use erase tool to erase a line between two cells but I don't know how to do this in Apple Page. Please teach me.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you want to merge two cells? select all the cells you want to merge and merge them together by selecting "format" menu->"table"->"merge cells"

Comment: wow. great great great :D. just because I don't know what english word to express, so I cannot search it :D thanks very much :)